# Ubuntu Slave Node (Jenkins) Error

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, slave

I recently set up a RHEL7 slave node in a dev Jenkins environment which simply ran a few Unix specific scripts via SSH.

The time has come to essentially replicate this yet in my companies Production environment (using a different slave node (Ubuntu 16.04), I have replicated the slave node configuration from the Dev jenkins and been working through the errors produced by the log, however I've been stuck at this stage for awhile and can't find any documentation which is relevant to my situation.

I am getting the following error:

```
    [02/15/17 10:47:11] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/home/jenkins" && java  -jar slave.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Root directory not writable
    at hudson.remoting.FileSystemJarCache.<init>(FileSystemJarCache.java:44)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.runWithStdinStdout(Launcher.java:477)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:251)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:201)
hudson.util.IOException2: Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:984)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$400(SSHLauncher.java:137)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:725)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:706)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:365)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:310)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:389)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:976)
    ... 7 more
[02/15/17 10:47:11] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/15/17 10:47:11] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I have double, triple checked the permissions of the root directory (home/jenkins/jenkins_slave) and they're fine. If I attempt to manually run java -jar slave.jar on the slave node I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Are you running slave agent from an interactive console?
If so, you are probably using it incorrectly.
See http://wiki.jenkins ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launching+slave.jar+from+from+console
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>
```

I just don't understand, because the permissions and config are identical so it must be something environmental? Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to check the state of SELinux (if installed) using `getenforce` command. It's possible that corporate image has some restricting policies. If you get `Enforcing` as a return of the command, please refer to SELinux documentation and corporate policies for further research. Command `ausearch -i` will help you to prove that some access is forbidden in that case.

Comment: Hi @doz10us thanks for the reply - I checked SELinux's status only to find that it isn't even installed haha.

Comment: Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Your home is not `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave` but `home/jenkins` - at least according to the log output you provided (`Starting slave process: cd "/home/jenkins" [...]`). So you should change your startup configuration of the slave and cd into `/home/jenkins/jenkins_slave`